# Reservation system for support environments

Tags: windows, virtualization, reservation

I work for a software developer, where part of my job is to administer the environment that my support team uses to triage client issues. I am looking for a utility that manages reserved access to instances of our application so that any particular issue can be worked on without affecting (or being affected by) other users.

Is there any Windows based utility for checking access to a resource in and out?

Access might be via client executable or web, and preferably users are logging in with a unique identity.

**Note**: A resource could be a lot of things. Windows RDP, Web, SSMS, or exe, to name a few. I understand that this is vague, but the application really does have a variety of access types. I'm also tinkering with some imperfect ideas. One utilizes [Remote Desktop Manager](http://remotedesktopmanager.com/) connections managed through [Secret Server](http://thycotic.com/products/secret-server/features/check-out/). The other is the temporary provisioning of container based VMs that are removed when finished. That would be a totally new field for me, and I'm not sure of the likelihood of success.